# Problema para mocker un repository

Tags: java, mock, repository, mocking

Estoy haciendo test unitarios en java, pero resulta que en el codigo del test el objeto `whiteListRepository` siempre me trae un `nullPointerException` (despues del `when`) porque al parecer no se logra mockear bien, que podria ser?

**Controller**:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/match-whitelist")
public class WhitelistController {

    @Autowired
    private WhitelistServiceImpl whitelistService;

    @GetMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<WhitelistResponseDTO> findById(@RequestParam(name = "id", required = true) Long id) {
        log.info("Calling findById with {}", id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(whitelistService.findById(id));
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<WhitelistResponseDTO> save(@Valid @RequestBody WhitelistAddRequestDTO whiteListAddRequestDTO) {
        log.info("Calling save with {}", whiteListAddRequestDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(whitelistService.save(whiteListAddRequestDTO));
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
public class WhitelistServiceImpl implements WhitelistService {

    public WhitelistServiceImpl(WhiteListRepository whiteListRepository, WhitelistMapper whitelistMapper) {
        this.whiteListRepository = whiteListRepository;
        this.whitelistMapper = whitelistMapper;
    }

    @Value("${api.match.expired.whitelist}")
    private Long timeExpired;

    private WhiteListRepository whiteListRepository;

    private WhitelistMapper whitelistMapper;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public WhitelistResponseDTO findById(Long id) {
        WhiteList whiteList = whiteListRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
        return whitelistMapper.toDTO(whiteList);
    }
}
```

**Repo:**

```
@Repository("whiteListRepository")
public interface WhiteListRepository extends JpaRepository<WhiteList, Long> {

    public Optional<WhiteList> findById(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

**Test:**

```
public class WhitelistServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private WhitelistServiceImpl whitelistServiceImpl;
    private WhiteList whiteList;
    @Mock
    private WhiteListRepository whiteListRepository;
    @Mock
    private WhitelistMapper whitelistMapper;
    private static final WhitelistStatus STATUS_ACTIVE = WhitelistStatus.ACTIVE;
    private static final String AFIP_CODE = "1111111";
    private static final String CUIT = "20275892249";
    private static final String EMPLOYEE_ID = "L1005987";
    private static final String SEVEN_DAYS_AGO = "L1005987";

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        whiteListRepository = mock(WhiteListRepository.class);
        whitelistMapper = mock(WhitelistMapper.class);
        whitelistServiceImpl = new WhitelistServiceImpl(whiteListRepository, whitelistMapper);
        //MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAddExceptionLowerOrEqualThan15Days() {

        doReturn(Optional.ofNullable(WhiteList.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .cuit(CUIT)
                .afipCode(AFIP_CODE)
                .employeeId(EMPLOYEE_ID)
                .status(STATUS_ACTIVE)
                .createdAt(mockingLowerOrEqualThan15Days())
                .updateAt(mockingToday())
                .build())).when(whiteListRepository).findByStatusAndAfipCodeAndCuit(STATUS_ACTIVE, AFIP_CODE, CUIT);


        WhiteList whiteList = builder();
        WhitelistResponseDTO expected = whitelistMapper.toDTO(whiteList);
        WhitelistResponseDTO result = whitelistMapper.toDTO(builderExpected());
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, result);
    }
}
```